# Can't use io.open in home directory - Lua

Tags: macos, io, lua

I'm writing a Mac OS program, and I have the following lines:

```
os.execute("cd ~/testdir")
configfile = io.open("configfile.cfg", "w")
configfile:write("hello")
configfile:close()
```

The problem is, it only creates the configfile in the scripts current directory instead of the folder I have just cd' into. I realised this is because I'm using a console command to change directory, then direct Lua code to write the file. To combat this I changed the code to this:

```
configfile = io.open("~/testdir/configfile.cfg", "w")
```

However I get the following result:

```
lua: ifontinst.lua:22: attempt to index global 'configfile' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
ifontinst.lua:22: in main chunk
```

My question is, what's the correct way to use IO.Open to create a file in a folder I have just created in the users home directory?

I appreciate I'm making a rookie mistake here, so I apologise if you waste your time on me.

Comment: `os.execute("cd ~/testdir")` does not work as you expect because changing the current directory in a subprocess does not affect the parent process.

Answer (score 9):

You have problems with `~` symbol. In your `os.execute("cd ~/testdir")` is the shell who interprets the symbol and replaces it by your home path. However, in `io.open("~/testdir/configfile.cfg", "w")` is Lua who receives the string and Lua doesn't interprets this symbol, so your program tries to open a file in the incorrect folder. One simple solution is to call `os.getenv("HOME")` and concatenate the path string with your file path:

```
configfile = io.open(os.getenv("HOME").."/testdir/configfile.cfg", "w")
```

In order to improve error messages I suggests you to wrap `io.open()` using `assert()` function:

```
configfile = assert( io.open(os.getenv("HOME").."/testdir/configfile.cfg", "w") )
```

Comment: This worked. I really appreciate your answer. It never crossed my mind about io.open not interpreting the ~ symbol. I have learned from my mistake. Thank you. @Francisco